# When I use Font Awesome in Photoshop CS5.1, it crashes straight away

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, cs5

When I try to type with/edit a text layer that uses Font Awesome in Photoshop CS5.1, it crashes straight away.

I am using a late 2015 retina 4k mac, running High Sierra. However, this problem was still happening when I was running Yosemite.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Is there a fix for it at all? As it is super frustrating having to use SVG icons all the time when I can just use an icon font. (Other icon fonts work and don't cause me this problem)

Thanks in advance.

*EDIT*

- I have tried to install older versions, I have also uninstalled and reinstalled the font.
- I have tried the same version I have installed on my Mac on a macbook air late 2012 model, running Yosemite, using the same version of Photoshop and on a pc using the same version of Photoshop and they didn't have the issue at all.
- I used Font Awesome on an older Mac, think it was a 2011 model which was running Yosemite and I still had the same issue.
- I have tried also tried all of Adobe's suggestions for fixing problems with fonts. I.e. using Font Book to validate all fonts and clearing font cache, disabling font preview and using the Font Test script.

Comment: Do you have access to a newer version of Photoshop to test it? Maybe the free trial of 2017 Photoshop? It might be a compatibility issue.

Comment: I have tried the same version I have installed on my Mac on a macbook air using the same version and on a pc using the same version and they didn't have the issue at all.

*I am using a late 2015 retina 4k mac

Comment: So you're only having the issue on one specific machine you've installed it on?

Comment: Exactly that.

However, I used it on an older Mac, think it was a 2011 model and I still had the same issue..

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect that because it's vital information to solving your issue.

Comment: I have done that now, is there anything else people might want to know that could help them solve my issue?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what type of computer is experiencing the issue? is that the 2015 mac? Can you be more clear in your question? It's hard to follow everything you posted.

 Also, in what way is the computer that has the issue configured differently than your other computers?

Comment: Voting to close this as it is a tech support issue. Referring to Photoshop does not make this a graphic design question.

Comment: Where would you recommend posting this then, Lucian?

Comment: What other programs do you have installed on that system that isn't on the other computer that do not have the problem.

Comment: They are going to say adobe tech help forums

Comment: I have been using it on Illustrator (CS5.1) & InDesign (CS5.5) just fine.

Comment: Do you have access to a different copy of the font? It sounds like a font conflict. It could be ANYTHING in the font file that is causing the problem such as a single glyph. If you have no other issues, it points to Awesome as the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Photoshop CS5.1 is not compatible with Font Awesome.

There is a bug in it that causes it to crash that was patched in newer versions of PS. However, other CS5.1 apps do work find with Font Awesome.

This was tested cross platform across Mac and Windows.

There are no reported problems with current versions of PS CC.

A free trial of PS CC would allow you to test if there is problems. 
http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop/free-trial-download.html

PS by itself is only $10 a month as of 2017. You don't have to purchase the whole suite.

Comment: Hi there, further to your comment on the other post. It did not work on any version pre or post Yosemite.

Comment: No more discussion in comments. Lets continue this in chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68329/when-i-use-font-awesome-in-photoshop-cs5-1-it-crashes-straight-away

Comment: I don't have enough rep -.-

Comment: @KieranThompson-Oliver Well I do want to help you, I don't give up easily. Did this ever work at one point on a computer you've used? If so, what computer and what OS version?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have never had it working..

I have even tried to contact the people who make font awesome to see if they could help but they didn't get back to me.

Comment: Are you using font awesome 4.7? And does it work in any other programs on your computer?

Comment: Yeah, I am using the most up to date version. It works on llustrator (CS5.1) & InDesign (CS5.5) just fine.

Comment: I want to say that there is probably a bug in Photoshop CS5.1 that was patched in later versions. That's why it would work on your other programs. That would explain why it doesn't work on PC or on Mac for PS CS5.1.  Do you have access to a new version of PS?

Comment: Ah that sucks, unfortunately I don't.

Comment: You can get a free trial of PS from adobe just to check it out. I think you just need to make an account. Sorry I couldn't find a real solution to this

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a go. I imagine you are correct though. Thank you so much for your help. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score -1):

Photoshop, Indesign, and Illustrator are all programs that come from different original sources but are available under one entity (Adobe) now. They are coded and act differently. They don't share resources very well and are "made" to play nicely with each other. Sometimes, what works with one application doesn't with another. That aside, fonts are notoriously problematic. If you have a problem that involves a font, most likely the problem lies with the font. If your original has become corrupted, it doesn't matter how many times you reload it, it won't make you happy. Download a new copy of it.

Comment: Hi Stan,

I have tried to do this already. The problem still persists.

Comment: I have tried also tried all of Adobe's suggestions for fixing problems with fonts. I.e. using Font Book to validate all fonts and clearing font cache, disabling font preview and using the Font Test script.

Comment: @Kieran Thompson-Oliver If it's not the font itself it's your system configuration. You need to reinstall everything from scratch or start deleting things one by one. If you have creative cloud then the Adobe team can remote in and fix the problem *sometimes* they are actually really helpful *sometimes*.

Comment: @Kieran Thompson-Oliver even if you uninstall adobe products it doesn't really uninstall everything btw. That's why you need to reinstall osx if you can't get professional help.

Comment: I am confused as to why this would be the problem, as above I mentioned that I had the same issue on an older Mac I was using previously.

Comment: I am now using a new Mac which I also mentioned above.

Comment: @KieranThompson-Oliver No I thought this problem was only on one computer? You said you upgraded from Yosemite to High Sierra. That doesn't mean you cleaned out the computer. You just upgraded thats all.

Comment: "I used Font Awesome on an older Mac, think it was a 2011 model which was running Yosemite and I still had the same issue."

I said this above. I have upgraded my current mac to High Sierra from Yosemite and the problem still persists.

Comment: Then I also said this above: "I am using a late 2015 retina 4k mac, running High Sierra. However, this problem was still happening when I was running Yosemite."

Comment: @Kieran Thompson-Oliver Did this ever work for you on Yosemite? Did it work on an older version than Yosemite? If so what version?

Comment: Would you both continue your discussion in Meta rather than in comments?